# Zincblende structure, is it FCC or diamond face centred?

Tags: x-ray-crystallography

I want to calculate number of atoms or lattice points of the zincblende but
I can't distinguish the crystal shape or structure of Zincblende because :
According to the information of this website[Zincblende/sphalerite is based on a fcc lattice of anions](http://www.ilpi.com/inorganic/structures/zincblende/) 
As we know that FCC has just 4 atoms per unit cell.
In other hand my teacher said that Zincblende is similar to diamond structure which has 8 atoms per unit cell

Comment: The zincblende structure is the same structure of diamond but with alternating types of atoms. It can be also seen as two interpenetrating fcc structures. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_crystal_system#Zincblende_structure).

Comment: Also, fcc has 4 atoms per unit cell.

Comment: But when you want to calculate number of atoms of GaAs for example in a unit cell.  What is the number of atoms here is it 8 or 2(since there is two interpenetrated of fcc)?

Comment: Note: It is not clever to talk about the "unit cell" without qualification. A FCC lattice with trivial basis has one atom per *primitive* unit cell (as any Bravais lattice with trivial basis) but four atoms per *customary* unit cell (which is used to visualize the symmetry properties of the lattice).

Comment: But when we want to calculate number of atoms per unit cell in zincblende structure we consider it as a diamond as in this text: http://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Inorganic_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Inorganic_Chemistry_(Housecroft)/06%3A_Structures_and_energetics_of_metallic_and_ionic_solids/6.11%3A_Ionic_Lattices/6.11E%3A_Structure_-_Zinc_Blende_(ZnS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usual to call a lattice fcc even if it has more than one atom per primitive unit cell. That is, it is common to talk about the underlying Bravais lattice in crystals with non-trivial basis (i.e. more than one atom per primitive unit cell).

In this sense, diamond is a fcc lattice with two atoms per primitive unit cell and the same applies to the zincblende structure. Wikipedia has a [nice picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sphalerite-unit-cell-depth-fade-3D-balls.png) that shows that the fcc nature of the lattice.

To extend: The positions of atoms in a crystal can be described by giving a Bravais lattice, specified by vectors $\vec a_1, \vec a_2, \vec a_3$ and a "basis" of $n$ atoms with offsets $\vec b_1, \ldots, \vec b_n$ from the lattice site (the name is badly chosen as this has nothing to do with the basis of a vector space). That is, an atom of kind $i$ is found at the location
$$ \vec r = k \vec a_1 + l \vec a_2 + m \vec a_3 + \vec b_i $$
for any integers $k, l, m$.

The vectors $\vec a_1, \vec a_2, \vec a_3$ span the unit cell (note that this choice is not unique, for example we could use $2\vec a_1$ instead of $\vec a_1$ and use a larger basis).

The unit cell is called primitive if we cannot choose such a representation with a basis with less atoms (this choice is also not unique, we could for example use $\vec a_1, \vec a_2 + \vec a_3, \vec a_2 - \vec a_3$ instead). The Bravais lattice described by these vectors, however, is unique and tells us which kind of lattice the crystal posesses. In the case of zincblende and diamond this is an fcc lattice and we need two atoms placed at $\vec b_1$ and $\vec b_2$ (one of those can obviously be chosen to be zero).

The customary unit cell is chosen as to make the symmetry of the system apparent. So for fcc lattices we use a cubic unit cell which consists of 4 primitive unit cells (and therefore contains 4 atoms in copper and 8 in diamond or zincblende).